# why i see blank page when use mpdf library with ci view?

Tags: codeigniter, pdf, codeigniter-2

i use this [tutorial](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/204306/) to generate pdf files from html files like

the controller

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index() {

        $this->load->library('mpdf');
        $this->mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4');
        $html = $this->load->view("test");
        $txt = "hiiiiiiiiiii";
        $this->mpdf->WriteHTML($txt , 2);
        $this->mpdf->WriteHTML($html , 2);
        $this->mpdf->Output('ggg.pdf', 'I');
    }

    public function ahmed() {
        $this->load->view('test');
    }

    public function fakhr() {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }

    public function yahoo() {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }

}
```

the problem is , when i pass  `$html` to `WriteHTML()` function it generated a blank pdf and when i pass `$txt` variable to the same function printed the text `"hiiiii"...` 
so how to solve this problem any why i cant generate pdf from codeigniter views files..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to do this

```
$html = $this->load->view("test",array() , true);
```

Use third parameter as true so that it returns the view as string